# Is there a better way to generate this list of lookups and flatten a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django

I was curious about generating a list of queryset style lookups and this is what I came up with.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
["%s__%s" % (f.name, b.name) \
     for f in Foo._meta._fields() \
     if isinstance(f, django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey)\
     for b in f.related.parent_model._meta._fields()]
```

In practice I would do something like this,

```
fields = ["%s__%s" % (f.name, b.name) \
     for f in Foo._meta._fields() \
     if isinstance(f, django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey)\
     for b in f.related.parent_model._meta._fields()]

 return Foo.values_list(*fields)
```

This would return me a de-normalized collection of my database.  I am thinking there has to be a better way.  Something that doesn't use the `_meta` and `_fields` attributes.  Or simply something that is part of the [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/) object that will do this.  I just couldn't find it.

I did find [django-composition](https://github.com/daevaorn/django-composition) but not sure what it does from the README file alone.